# Setting the subfigures horizontally in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex

Figures are plotted vertically but i want to set them horizontally. Kindly guide me the possible options.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\hspace{-2.15cm}
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=Satisfied Requests,
    xlabel=Requests,
    height=5cm, width=8cm,
    legend cell align=left, legend columns=-1, legend style={inner xsep=2pt, inner ysep=2pt,at={(0.365,0.216)},anchor=east,font=\tiny},
    label style={font=\small},
    legend columns=1,
    xticklabel style={anchor=near xticklabel},
    ymin=0.2, ymax=0.6, ytick={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6},
    xmin=0, xmax=1.1, xtick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
]
\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=square,red] table[x=x, y=y]   {a.txt};
%\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=asterisk,blue] table[x=x, y=y]  {Request vs. satisfied requests-2.txt};
%\addplot [thick,mark size=2.3pt,mark=diamond,black] table[x=x, y=y] {Request vs. satisfied requests-3.txt};
%\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=o,brown] table[x=x, y=y] {Request vs. satisfied requests-4.txt};
%\legend{Proactive high load, Proactive low load, Reactive low load, Reactive high load}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}
\end{subfigure}

\hspace{-2.05cm}
 \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=Satisfied Requests,
    xlabel=Cache size,
    height=5cm, width=8cm,
    legend cell align=left, legend columns=-1, legend style={inner xsep=2pt, inner ysep=2pt,at={(0.996,0.21)},anchor=east,font=\tiny},
    label style={font=\small},
    legend columns=1,
    xticklabel style={anchor=near xticklabel},
    ymin=0, ymax=1.1, ytick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
    xmin=0, xmax=1.1, xtick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
]
\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=square,red] table[x=x, y=y]   {a.txt};
%\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=asterisk,blue] table[x=x, y=y]  {Cache vs. satisfied requests-2.txt};
%\addplot [thick,mark size=2.3pt,mark=diamond,black] table[x=x, y=y] {Cache vs. satisfied requests-3.txt};
%\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=o,brown] table[x=x, y=y] {Cache vs. satisfied requests-4.txt};
%\legend{Proactive high load, Proactive low load, Reactive low load, Reactive high load}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{-0.08cm}
\caption{Simulation results for Proactive vs. Reactive caching with low and high load. (a) Hit radio vs. Number of requests (b) Hit radio vs. cache size}
\label{LQI-timex}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

data file

```
x   y
0.1 0.53896
0.2 0.52122
0.3 0.50326
0.4 0.48145
0.5 0.45054
0.6 0.42319
0.7 0.40357
0.8 0.38396
0.9 0.36315
1   0.34668
```

Comment: It's wrong to place a `figure*` environment inside a `center` environment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but figure* is already inside the center environment and its not working for me

Comment: No one of us can compile that document, because we don't have the data files. Please provide one example data file so we can actually test things. Also you should *not* put the `figure*` inside the `center` environment.

Comment: So i add the data file and compile able code. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

a subfigure is positioned just like a big letter, you have a blank line between so they are in separate paragraphs so one above the other.

You can remove the paragraph break as below but the plots are wider than half the text width so you need to make them smaller, you need to choose to scale or show a smaller range.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
%???\ifCLASSINFOpdf \else \fi
%\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

% you have this twice but networks and semiconductor already the default
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

    \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=Satisfied Requests,
    xlabel=Requests,
    height=5cm, width=8cm,
    legend cell align=left, legend columns=-1, legend style={inner xsep=2pt, inner ysep=2pt,at={(0.365,0.216)},anchor=east,font=\tiny},
    label style={font=\small},
    legend columns=1,
    xticklabel style={anchor=near xticklabel},
    ymin=0.2, ymax=0.6, ytick={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6},
    xmin=0, xmax=1.1, xtick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
]
\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=square,red] table[x=x, y=y]   {a.txt};
%\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=asterisk,blue] table[x=x, y=y]  {Request vs. satisfied requests-2.txt};
%\addplot [thick,mark size=2.3pt,mark=diamond,black] table[x=x, y=y] {Request vs. satisfied requests-3.txt};
%\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=o,brown] table[x=x, y=y] {Request vs. satisfied requests-4.txt};
%\legend{Proactive high load, Proactive low load, Reactive low load, Reactive high load}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=Satisfied Requests,
    xlabel=Cache size,
    height=5cm, width=8cm,
    legend cell align=left, legend columns=-1, legend style={inner xsep=2pt, inner ysep=2pt,at={(0.996,0.21)},anchor=east,font=\tiny},
    label style={font=\small},
    legend columns=1,
    xticklabel style={anchor=near xticklabel},
    ymin=0, ymax=1.1, ytick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
    xmin=0, xmax=1.1, xtick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
]
\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=square,red] table[x=x, y=y]   {a.txt};
%\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=asterisk,blue] table[x=x, y=y]  {Cache vs. satisfied requests-2.txt};
%\addplot [thick,mark size=2.3pt,mark=diamond,black] table[x=x, y=y] {Cache vs. satisfied requests-3.txt};
%\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=o,brown] table[x=x, y=y] {Cache vs. satisfied requests-4.txt};
%\legend{Proactive high load, Proactive low load, Reactive low load, Reactive high load}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{-0.08cm}
\caption{Simulation results for Proactive vs. Reactive caching with low and high load. (a) Hit radio vs. Number of requests (b) Hit radio vs. cache size}
\label{LQI-timex}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you david but they are still overlapping. Can you please help me in setting them on a a4 page size width

Comment: you are specifying the plot size as `height=5cm, width=8cm,` which means you can not get two in a column, use `figure*` so it spans two columns or use something like `height=3cm, width=5cm,` for each plot @TayyabaLiaqat